# How to create a shell script to delete a particular file in loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command-line

Actually I am intending to create a shell script executing which should delete particular files/folders continuously say every 5 seconds which is continuously being generated by a application

[ Below data being used is a dummy so that it becomes easy to understand and probably help others too in general ]

**Target App Package name** -    com.example.mypackage

**Target App Launch Activity Name** - com.activity.launcher

**Target App's files to be deleted** - /sdcard/Android/data/app/log1 , /sdcard/Android/data/app/log2

**Deletion Interval** : Every 5 Seconds

**Start Trigger Point** : Only After i execute the shell script

**End Point** : Deletion Loop Process Should end automatically after target App is no longer active ( Hence mentioned activity Name above )

Comment: Just as any other script. Try yourself and show here any problems you can't overcome.

Comment: @Tomasz Fair Enough , i will first try it on my own with whatever knowledge i have

Comment: you could do a process listing and search for the PID of the process, if a PID is found, then delete the file every 5 seconds. After the deletion, re check for the PID with a process listing. Make the loop condition be if the PID is still active.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short bash script I came up with. Note you will need to replace `logger\.sh` in the grep statements with the name of the process that you want to monitor. In this case it is checking for a process named "logger.sh" and grabbing the PID.

```
#!/bin/bash

pid=$(ps aux | grep "logger\.sh" | head -n 1 |  awk '{print $2}');

if [ "$pid" != "" ] 
    then
    pidFound=1;
    while [ "$pidFound" = 1 ]
    do
        rm /sdcard/Android/data/app/log1;
        rm /sdcard/Android/data/app/log2;
        sleep 5;
        pid=$(ps aux | grep "logger\.sh" | head -n 1 |  awk '{print $2}');
        if [ "$pid" != "" ]; then
            pidFound=1;
        else
            pidFound=0;
            break
        fi
    done
fi
```

Comment: Also could use "pgrep program_name" to get the PID instead of ps aux with unnecessary pipes and extra commands.

Comment: also, using `while pgrep -f "logger.sh" >/dev/null 2>&1; do ... done` would eliminate the need for the $pid variable, AND the `if; then;fi` that wraps the loop.   With this, we only care about the exit code from pgrep (0 for "found 1 or more matching processes", 1 for "no matches found". see `man pgrep`), so we redirect stdout & stderr to /dev/null.

Comment: also note: any method of searching the process list (including `ps|grep` and `pgrep`) may fail when searching for a script IF the script uses something like "#!/usr/bin/env sh" instead of "#!/bin/sh".   Using `env` in a #! line screws up the process name.

Comment: @johndoe Hello sir , taking some help from your answer i was able to create a bash script from scratch on m own... Although it has few issues . Can you please help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/545345/bash-script-not-working-as-expected